# Adding custom header in httprequest restkit 0.20 ios

Tags: ios, iphone, httprequest, restkit-0.20

I am trying to add a custom header to all the http request from the app but on server side I am not getting it.

I tried following methods:

1.setting header in `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
 [request addValue:headerString forHTTPHeaderField:@"deviceDetails"];
 NSLog( @"%@",[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"deviceDetails"]);
```

Here I get null just after setting the header value. Not sure what is happening.

2.setting default header in `RKObjectManager`

```
   [manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"deviceDetails" value:headerString];
```

Here header seems to be set but on server there is no header field with key "deviceDetails"

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request =[self _createPostRequestWithParams:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] andPath:path];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:20];
    NSLog(@"%@",[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"deviceDetails"]);
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
    [manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];

        [manager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:self.offlineService.user.username password:self.offlineService.user.password];

     [manager addResponseDescriptor: [self _getResponseDescriptorWithKeyPath:keyPath andResponseClass:responseClass]];
    [manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"deviceDetails" value:@"String value" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self _createOperationForRequest:request successcallback:requestSuccessful failurecallback:requestFailure target:target manager:manager];

     [operation start];
```

_createOperationForRequest:

```
- (RKObjectRequestOperation *)_createOperationForRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request successcallback:(SEL)requestSuccessful failurecallback:(SEL)requestFailed target:(id)target  manager:(RKObjectManager *)manager {

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
             success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,RKMappingResult *result) {

             }
             failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,NSError *error){

             }];
    return operation;
}
```

In above code both basic authentication and device details header are received on the server side.

Comment: The second method should work. This is what I do (and it works) `[self.objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Charset" value:@"UTF-8"];` You could try with a sniffer to see if the problem lies in the server or not

Comment: What is `request` in your first bit of code? How are you sending your request. As per @Francesco, your second bit of code is correct assuming you use the manager to send the request...

Comment: @Wain you are correct. After initializing the manager I either use the manager or use its httpclient for every request

Comment: Thanks all for reply. @Francesco I did try to send the request using PostMan and it worked fine so the problem lies in sending request from iPhone. I will add more code in the question.

Comment: @Wain Sorry for the delayed reply. I have added the code to send the request.

Comment: Why not use `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` ? Use Charles to check what is sent.

Comment: but method does not allow me to set request body. That I set to NSMutableURLRequest. I have a JSON string as well that I would like to set with the request. Can you tell me a way by which I can set header as well as set Request body?

Comment: Have you tried to enable restkit network tracing?